# jetty Logger error : org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger

Tags: jetty, logging

Im getting this error, What is the reason it?

Starting Server
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Logger;
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.(AbstractHandler.java:33)
    at com.usta.sunucu.Sunucu.(Sunucu.java:30)
    at com.usta.sunucu.Sunucu.main(Sunucu.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have mis-match between different Jetty classes on your classpath.

It appears that method was added in 7.5.0-RC2 and 8.0.0, any versions of Jetty before those version will not have it.

It looks like you have a version of `jetty-server.jar` that is newer than 7.5.0 / 8.0.0 and a version of `jetty-util.jar` that is older.